# Write a scope in rails to fetch simaliar objects by categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need help to write a scope to fetch similar businesses.

My Business model has many categories. So I want a scope to query all businesses with similar categories except the present record.

#### business.rb

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
 ........
  has_many :business_categories
  has_many :categories , through: :business_categories
  scope :similar_businesses, -> (current_business_id, category_name) {joins(:categories).where(categories:{name: category_name}).where.not(id: current_business_id, name: category_name)}

........
```

#### category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :business_categories
  has_many :businesses,, through: :business_categories
  validates :name ,presence: true
```

### business_controller.rb

```
def show
.....
@business = Business.friendly.find(params[:id])
@similar_businesses = Business.similar_businesses(@business.id, @business.categories.pluck(:name))
.....
```

#### business/show.html.erb

```
<%@similar_businesses.each do |business|%>
   <%=business.business_name%> <br>
 <%end%>
```

With this get up. I have the PG error

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = bigint
LINE 1: ...tegories"."category_id" WHERE "categories"."name" IN (SELECT...
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `Category` model has a `category_name`(or something similar) attribute and by similar categories you meant categories having the same `category_name`. This is how you can get all the  businesses with similar category:

```
scope :businesses_by_category, ->(category_name) { joins(:categories).where(categories: { name: category_name }) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just one question. Where did you get the current_business_id from?

Comment: `I want a scope to query all businesses with similar categories except the present record.`  By this, I think you meant that you have a record with you that you want to skip.

Comment: If you do not have any object that you want to skip, you can remove the `where.not(id: current_bussiness_id)` part from the query-

Comment: I have an error ‘wrong number of arguments(given 0 , expected 1)’

Comment: scope :businesses_by_category, ->(category_name) { joins(:categories).where(categories: { name: category_name }) }

Comment: I had forgotten to add the `category_name` as an argument to the scope.

Comment: yes that’s exactly what I want. So on the show business page, the present business id will not be queried

Comment: where on the scope?

Comment: `scope :businesses_by_category, ->(category_name) { joins(:categories).where(categories: { name: category_name }) }`

Comment: if you have a current business record that needs to be skipped, add the `current_bussiness_id` as a second argument to the scope:
`scope :businesses_by_category, ->(category_name, current_bussiness_id) { joins(:categories).where(categories: { name: category_name }).where.not(id: current_bussiness_id) }`

Comment: still the same error wrong number of arguments

Comment: You should pass the arguments to the scope:
`Business. businesses_by_category(category_name, current_bussiness_id)`

Comment: scope :myscope, -> ( category_name, current_business_id ) ... error wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2). what I am doing wrong

Comment: when are you getting the error? while defining the scope or while using it?

Comment: when using the scope

Comment: Since this scope requires 2 arguments, `category_name` for filtering the businesses based on category and `current_bussiness_id` to ignore the current business record; you need to pass these arguments while using the scope:
`Business. myscope(category_name, current_bussiness_id)`

Comment: Ok so on the show action. I used @myscope= Business.myscope(category_name, current_business_id)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231007/discussion-between-foliwe83-and-sachin-singh).